# Filter an array by date and after that by Name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array in js called: areas

```
var areas =  [
 ["Id" : 1, "Date" : "2016-04-01", "Name" : "Ramon"],
 ["Id" : 2, "Date" : "2016-04-01", "Name" : "Ester"],
 ["Id" : 3, "Date" : "2016-04-01", "Name" : "Sandy"],
 ["Id" : 4, "Date" : "2016-04-02", "Name" : "Ruiz"],
 ["Id" : 5, "Date" : "2016-04-03", "Name" : "Mark"],
 ["Id" : 6, "Date" : "2016-04-04", "Name" : "Vadim"],
 ["Id" : 7, "Date" : "2016-04-06", "Name" : "Vanny"],
 ["Id" : 8, "Date" : "2016-04-09", "Name" : "John"]
]
```

for example to before that I have an filter in ajax which will classify them by date and when
I am doing for:

```
for (var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++ ){
      console.log("Date " + areas[i].Date + " Name " + areas[i].Name);
}
```

Output will be this

```
Date 2016-04-01 Name Ramon
Date 2016-04-01 Name Ester
Date 2016-04-01 Name Sandy
Date 2016-04-02 Name Ruiz
```

But I want if it is the same date to filter by Name

In this way:

```
Date 2016-04-01 Name Ester
Date 2016-04-01 Name Ramon
Date 2016-04-02 Name Ruiz
Date 2016-04-01 Name Sandy
```

I need to make another loop or how?

Thanks

Comment: Inside `for`, use `areas[i]`. Use array of objects.

Comment: Sorry just made a mistake sure it will be areas[i].Date, and areas[i].Name

Comment: filter by name? looks more than sort by name.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/whr4taug/

`Filter an array by date and after that by Name in JavaScript`

your question speak for itself - you need filter function, which js has - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

And it can do all sorting in one loop. Or you can add multiple functions, each with it's sorting

```
var areas =  [
    {"Id" : 1, "Date" : "2016-04-01", "Name" : "Ramon"},
    {"Id" : 2, "Date" : "2016-04-01", "Name" : "Ester"},
    {"Id" : 3, "Date" : "2016-04-01", "Name" : "Sandy"},
    {"Id" : 4, "Date" : "2016-04-02", "Name" : "Ruiz"},
    {"Id" : 5, "Date" : "2016-04-03", "Name" : "Mark"},
    {"Id" : 6, "Date" : "2016-04-04", "Name" : "Vadim"},
    {"Id" : 7, "Date" : "2016-04-06", "Name" : "Vanny"},
    {"Id" : 8, "Date" : "2016-04-09", "Name" : "John"}
]

var filtered = areas.filter(function(el){
    if (el.Name == 'Ramon' && el.Date == '2016-04-01') return el;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

also your `areas` decalration is wrong (not sure if typo or not) - js doesn't have associated arrays, only objects for that purpose

If your requirement is to do it with ajax, then I'm not sure why you need js at all? Just do two ajax requests, and that's all

If you want to filter them inside `for` loop, just use same comparison

```
for (var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++ ){
  if (areas[i].Name == 'Ramon' && areas[i].Date == '2016-04-01') {
    console.log("Date " + areas[i].Date + " Name " + areas[i].Name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Here for example:                                                                                      `var filtered = areas.filter(function(el){
    if (el.Name == 'Ramon' && el.Date == '2016-04-01') return el;
}); `                                                                                                                          how to make it in this for                                                                              'for (var i = 0; i < areas.length; i++ ){
      
}'  ??

Comment: @detector why do you want to use `for` for this? I will add `for` variant, but `filter` is more appropriate IMO

Comment: but how to compare each date and name in `for` loop and after that to make this filter??

Comment: what do you mean by `how`? have you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators ?